# how to convert imu from left-handed rule to right-handed rule

Tags: imu, navigation, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, i am trying to use robot_localization to estimate mobile robots position/

I just read REP-103 and noticed that ROS follows right-handed rule.

Question :

Now i am using imu sensor (3dm-gx4-25) with imu package ([KumarRobotics/imu_3dm_gx4](https://github.com/KumarRobotics/imu_3dm_gx4))
and when i visulaize the sensor with rviz, i can see that it is left-handed rule imu.

I dont really know how to convert this to right-handed rule, can any one help with this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353799/how-to-convert-imu-from-left-handed-rule-to-right-handed-rule/) by [lgkimjy](https://answers.ros.org/users/55389/lgkimjy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All you need to do is define the frame of the IMU relative to the base_link with the correct rotation and orientation.
If the IMU would already be using the REP-103 coordinate system the very basic urdf would look something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<robot name="basic" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  <link name="base_link">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
  </link>
  <link name="imu"/>
  <joint name="imu_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.3"/>
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="imu"/>
  </joint>
</robot>
```

Would produce the output as (red=x, green=y, blue=z):

[image: image description]

In the linked repository the orientation of the IMU is depicted as Z down and Y to the "right". You need to take that orientation into account in the definition of your frames. To do that you need to rotate it around the X axis.

The rotation is in radians so rotate it by PI for 180 degrees. `<origin rpy="3.1416 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.3"/>`
The basic robot would look like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<robot name="basic" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  <link name="base_link">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
  </link>
  <link name="imu"/>
  <joint name="imu_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="3.1416 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.3"/>
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="imu"/>
  </joint>
</robot>
```

Output and the image in the linked git repo:

[image: image description]
[image: image description]

---

To easily inspect your urdf you might want to install the package [urdf_tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf_tutorial).

replace `<ros_distro>` with your distribution

`sudo apt install ros-<ros_distro>-urdf-tutorial`

for kinetic:

`sudo apt install ros-kinetic-urdf-tutorial`

Then assuming you saved the above robot description as `basic.xacro` you could just run:

```
cd /path/to/saved/xacro
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=basic.xacro
```

To verify that everything seems to be working normally you could install some plugins to visualize the IMU output in rviz. One example would be [rviz_imu_plugin](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz_imu_plugin). Have not used that plugin in a long time, you would probably need to have your URDF "running" and change the fixed_frame to base_link in Rviz to get sensible output.

---

Originally posted by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) with karma: 591 on 2020-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1